# Javascript embedding

Tags: javascript

Every time I try embedding a URL no matter which url I use it always gives me this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

the code I use is

```
<script src="URL" type="text/javascript">
        </script>
```

It does not matter which URL I point too it just always gives that error.

Comment: Based on the error it sounds like you're trying to put this HTML code in a `.js` file?

Comment: You don't happen to have script tags surrounding your code in the .js files, do you?

Comment: Please tell us what you put in the JS file...

Comment: the file is a .html file I've just realised the error, how would I go about embedding an html file? - I do not have access to it only to the link of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

That means there's HTML markup in a JavaScript file.  So either the `script` tag you're showing us is in a JavaScript file, or the JavaScript file that it's referencing contains HTML.

When putting JavaScript code in an HTML file, you need to wrap it in `script` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var foo = 'foo';
</script>
```

However, when putting JavaScript code in a *JavaScript* file, you don't need HTML tags.  Because it's not HTML:

```
var foo = 'foo';
```

Putting one kind of code in a file meant to be another kind of code results in a syntax error.